# Instance or static Controllers?

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

Multiple times I created a Model class and the including controller, whereas the controller was static. But often I saw people having their controllers as an instance which holds a model inside. Are there any advantages over static controller?

Comment: What framework? (tag your question correctly)

Comment: .Net, but does this make any difference towards any other?

Comment: Yes and no. With MVC or WPF, there is no question to answer - the controller or ViewModel is already an instance. In any case, a static controller is like using the default Form instance in WinForms - lots of problems (cleanup, concurrency) for no gain. What would you expect to gain with a static controller ? How would the static controller know which model and which view to talk to?

Comment: I would write code like "InsertIntoDatabase(MyModel m)", so basically this class controls the Model itself. So every method needs a provided model. In my view, this should be quite the same as storing a model inside this controller

Comment: One design principle of OOP that you should try to adhere to (regardless of the language) is the concept of `loose coupling`. This means each class knows as little as possible about types outside of itself which makes it easier to refactor, reuse, test, etc. I am guessing you are using (static) type references everywhere which will make your code very brittle (not easy to change) and goes against this concept. That is a big disadvantage to using/defining static types over instance types as with the latter it is much easier to stick to the principle of loose coupling (even using DI / IoC).

Comment: Actually the only static class I've got is the Controller itself. If I change something inside the Model, I need to change the controller a bit. But this also needs to be done when it is not static